# How can I use a Panasonic Lumix DMC-SZ1 as a camera attached to my computer?

Tags: tethering, stop-motion

I have the camera in the title but cannot attach and use the camera from a computer. I want a live feed of what the camera is seeing on the computer screen for clay stop-motion animation.

Is there any software that can support this? I tried Stop Motion Pro but it does not support Panasonic cameras.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the type of device driver. Camera may represent itself as a card reader (mass storage), PTP device, MTP device or WIA device. It is only possible to capture image with your camera in realtime if it is WIA device.

You may get additional info from "Device manager" if you find your camera there when it's connected.